# Can a user clear the local storage of an HTML5 based iOS application?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ios8, safari

Will iOS clear the local storage of any HTML5 based app if the `Settings-> General-> Safari-> Clear History and Website Data` is clicked by the user? or Is this option only for clearing Safari data?

If this option only for Safari, is there any way a user can clear the HTML5 app's local storage?

Note: The HTML5 app can have local storage, session storage, web sql db and anything related local storage.

Comment: Are you asking "can I assume they can't", or are you asking if there's a straightforward way to do that? I dont know the answer to the latter, but the former is surely false.

Comment: @doldt Do you mean they can clear local storage data of any HTML5 iOS app? If yes, how?